# M2Eclipse (M2E) build errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, m2e

I have installed the `m2e` plugin for Eclipse and used it to create a simple archetype. I wrote a small test driver and am trying to build the project (via Maven) and compile my Java sources into class files.

I go to`Run >> Run Configurations` and create a `New Maven Build`. I name it and set its base directory to be my project root.

When I try to select `Goals` it doesn't see any and so I can't add/specify any. I click the `Run` button. Here is my console output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.me:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\me\workbench\eclipse\workspace\MyProject\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.artifactId' is missing. @ line 145, column 17
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.groupId' is missing. @ line 144, column 14
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.version' for : must be a valid version but is ''. @ line 146, column 14
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

The `<build>` tag in my pom.xml is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId></groupId>
            <artifactId></artifactId>
            <version></version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compiler:compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

A few things:

- What should my `artifactId`, `groupId` and `version` be if this is the (standard) Maven `compile` phase?
- Is this the correct way to launch a Maven build (through `Run Configurations`)? In Ant there is a plugin that lets you see all of the targets defined in your `build.xml`; I see no such analog in Maven/m2e.
- Why does something as simple as *compile* require plugins? One would think this would be a standard part of any build tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put anything as you are using all the defaults settings of the maven compiler. If you really want to specify it you can do it this way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks! After reinspecting the pom.xml I see an error highlighted in red (by Eclipse) on the `<execution>` element I pasted in above. The error reads: *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compiler:compile (execution: default, phase: compile).* Could this have anything to do with what you are talking about? If so, what is the remedy?

Comment: Also, with regards to the way I am kicking off the build, is this the standard way of invoking Maven/m2e from inside Eclipse (through Run Configurations)?

Comment: What do you want to do? Maven helps you build and package source code. Compilation is just one step of such process. Moreover, this step is done by the Eclipse Java compiler in Eclipse. You might consider sending a more detailed question to the Maven user mailing list for more help.

Comment: I believe my question is confusing because I am a "*Maven newbie*" and am perhaps not asking the right question. All I want to do is compile my project inside of Eclipse, but using Maven (via the m2e plugin). Can you please tell me what my `<build>` tag (and/or Run Configuration) need to look like, and tell me what steps I need to take in order to achieve this? And thanks for being patient with me!

Comment: I read the Maven doc! And nowhere in it does it show any indication of the error I am getting (with regards to the maven-compiler-plugin). I have spent all day reading the doc and did not just write this question out of laziness!!!

Comment: Ok, but read the error reported. It says that there are 3 missing values for the compiler and they indicate on which line of your pom.xml. I don't say you are lazy, I am just pointing that you probably lack the basic Maven concepts and that is why you don't understand completely the reported errors. If you go to the Maven compiler plugin usage page, you will see exactly what I answered you

Comment: @AdamTannon: **Adam**, compiler plugin is by default bound to "compile" phase. You need to read [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) article to fill in the knowledge gaps. Maven works in a way that by default (and that means for 90% of projects) you don't need to change anything. For rest 5% perhaps you olny need to configure your plugin, without changing the `<execution>/<phase>`. And only when you know what `<phase>` is and you know what you want to achieve, you change that.